# How to convert date into timeago

Tags: javascript, html, time, timeago

I am trying to convert a date field in a "timeago" format using jquery.timeago.js

```
$("time.timeago").timeago();

var userSpan = document.createElement("span");
userSpan.setAttribute("class", "text-muted");
userSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.usernameSender +" | "));
var timeTag = document.createElement("time");
timeTag.setAttribute("class", "timeago");
timeTag.setAttribute("datetime",document.createTextNode(message.date));
userSpan.appendChild(timeTag);
```

This javascript will genearate the following code

```
<span class="text-muted">user1 | <time class="timeago" datetime="[object Text]"></time></span>
```

My problem is that the result of datetime is [object Text]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the result of datetime is [object Text]

Well, yes, because you tell JavaScript to do that:

```
timeTag.setAttribute("datetime",document.createTextNode(message.date));
```

Try

```
timeTag.setAttribute("datetime", message.date);
```

Attribute values are strings, whereas DOM nodes (including text nodes) are objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a minor issue. The datetime field is now populated as 1434389197000 not as 2015-06-10 16:41:09. Do you know a quick fix for this

Comment: Ah well, I assumed `message.date` was already in the right format. You can use `var d = new Date(parseInt(message.date))` to get a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods) object, from which you then use methods like `getDay()` to construct your date string. Or you could use a library like moment.js, like **Mohamad shiralizadeh** suggests.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have still to convert the date but that is another question. Thank you for your help